# Getting return value of a function run by schedule

Tags: python, return, scheduled-tasks, schedule

So I have a function that checks to see if my favorite sports team plays that day:

```
def checkGameDay():

today = str(datetime.date.today())
yyyymmdd = today.replace('-', '')
#yyyymmdd = '20171104' #test date that toronto played on (lost 6-4 to stL)
url = 'http://scores.nbcsports.msnbc.com/ticker/data/gamesMSNBC.js.asp?sport=%s&period=%s'
r = requests.get(url % ('NHL', yyyymmdd))
json_parsed = r.json()
check = 0

for game_str in json_parsed.get('games', []):
    game_tree = ElementTree.XML(game_str)
    away_tree = game_tree.find('visiting-team')
    home_tree = game_tree.find('home-team')
    gamestate_tree = game_tree.find('gamestate')
    home_nickname = home_tree.get('nickname')
    away_nickname = away_tree.get('nickname')
    home_alias = home_tree.get('alias')
    away_alias = away_tree.get('alias')
    away_score = away_tree.get('score')
    home_score = home_tree.get('score')
    x = 0;
    gamesToday = len(json_parsed.get('games', []))

    if away_alias == 'Tor' or home_alias == 'Tor':
        checkGoal()
        print "Toronto is playing today"
        return True         

    else:
        check = check + 1

    if check == gamesToday:
        print "Toronto does not play today" 
        return False
```

I am a novice programmer so please ignore any "good practices" or "more efficient ways" that I am missing!

If Toronto plays on that given day, True will be returned, and False when they don't. I want this value to be returned so I can use it's result later in the code although I can't figure out how to get the return of a scheduled event.

I set up the schedule using this code:

```
schedule.every().day.at("18:00").run(checkGameDay)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I know the returns should be triggered because the prints work perfectly fine!

Anybody know how I can create a variable that takes on this returned value? Thanks so much! I am so stuck on this...

Comment: The problem with your code is you are returning value in a loop which should not be the case. Try defining a variable outside the loop which updates itself after every loop iteration and you can return and store that variable in your other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 bool_value = False

def test_function():
    global bool_value
    #bool_value = False

    for i in range(10):
        if i%2 == 1:
            bool_value = True
        else:
            bool_value = False

    #return bool_value

storedVariable = bool_value
```

Do not return any value from the function. Define the variable globally and update it for later use.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Bhushan, I changed my function so that the variable is defined outside of the loop as you mentioned although I can't use your last line because of the scheduler I am trying to use, I need to get the return value of the function at that time and it doesn't seem to work when I try something like: `bool_value = schedule.every().day.at("18:00").run(checkGameDay)` Thanks!

Comment: So, just for my understanding when you run the scheduler it can return more than 1 value?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! Unfortunately, using a global variable doesn't work either... I believe it would work in a regular situation but because of how I'm calling the function using schedules is screwing things up. Any other ideas?